# Activate Maven profile if no other profile activated

Tags: maven-2, maven-profiles

I have a project that has several profiles. How do you make one of the profiles activate only if no other profiles are active?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As explained in [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html):

> Profiles can also be active by default
>   using a configuration like the
>   following:
>
> ```
> <profiles>
>   <profile>
>     <id>profile-1</id>
>     <activation>
>       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
>     </activation>
>     ...
>   </profile>
> </profiles>
> ```
>
> This profile will automatically be
>   active for all builds unless another
>   profile in the same pom is activated
>   using one of the previously described
>   methods. All profiles that are active
>   by default are automatically
>   deactivated when a profile in the pom
>   is activated on the command line or
>   through its activation config.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying! I thought activeByDefault meant that it will always be active.

Comment: "another profile in the same pom is activated" this is an important point, if you use multi-module, the parent profiles should appear in the child pom event if empty. Else the "activateByDefault" will always be activated, even for other profiles.